# Global object returns original value even thou its been replaced

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

On initial page load, I create a global object. Then set its value with a function.

```
function set_globals(table){
    // Setup Local Storage
    setLocalStorage();

    // DEBUGGING
    debug = AC.debug;
    debug == true ? console.log('Debugging is on.') : console.log('Debugging is off.');

    // URL
    current_url = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + window.location.pathname;

    // PAGINATION
    page_data   = {
        "_token": $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'),
    };
    paginate    = true;
    pagination  = {};
    setPaginationData(table.pagination, table.config.table.id)

    // TABLE
    table_restore   = true;
    // SEARCH
    searched        = false;
    //Downloading
    downloadingData = false;
}
```

The function.

```
function setPaginationData(data, table_id){
   pagination[table_id] = data;

   if(pagination[table_id].next_page_url == null){
        paginate = false;
   } 

   debug == true ? console.log('Pagination Data', pagination[table_id]) : false;
}
```

The object data on the initial page load looks like this.

```
{
 "total":6159,
 "per_page":100,
 "current_page":2,
 "last_page":62,
 "next_page_url":"localhost/pagination?page=2",
 "prev_page_url":null,
 "from":101,
 "to":200,
 "data":[{REMOVED}]
}
```

When I run my search filter. I return a new pagination object from an AJAX request and is set using the function from above.

```
function searchTable(table_config){
    searched = true;

    var search_id     = table_config.table.id+'_search';
    var search_box    = document.getElementById(search_id);
    var search        = search_box.value;
    var table_header  = document.getElementById(table_config.table.id + '_head');
    var table_headers = table_header.firstElementChild.children;


    // Get columns that are searchable
    var search_fields = get_searchable(table_headers);

    var filters = get_column_filters(table_config);

    var post = {
        "_token": $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'),
        "search": search,
        "search_fields" : search_fields,
        "filters" : filters,
    };

    debug == true ? console.log('Search:', search, 'Filters:', filters) : false;


    dimTable(table_config.table.id);

    page_data = post;

    var search_url = addSlash(current_url) + table_config.table.urls.search;

    $.post(search_url, post, function(data){
        debug == true ? console.log('Data returned from search:', data) : false;

        clearTableBody(table_config.table.id);
        setPaginationData(data, table_config.table.id);
        populateTable(data.table, table_config);
        getNextPage(table_config);
    });
}
```

The "data" object that I am returning in is the exact same structure as the original object during page load but it is different data.

```
{
 "total":186,
 "per_page":100,
 "current_page":1,
 "last_page":2,
 "next_page_url":"localhost/search?page=2",
 "prev_page_url":null,
 "from":1,
 "to":100,
 "data":[{REMOVED}]
}
```

So why when I run my function to get the next page of data does it use the original value set on the object and not the one just set from the search?

```
function getNextPage(table_config){
    debug == true ? console.log('Getting next page of pagination', table_config, pagination[table_config.table.id]) : false;
    checkSort(table_config.table.id); 

    if(pagination[table_config.table.id].current_page < pagination[table_config.table.id].last_page){
        loadingData(table_config.table.id, true);
        var page = pagination[table_config.table.id].current_page + 1;
        var page_url = addSlash(current_url) + table_config.table.urls.pagination + '?page=' + page;

        $.post(page_url, page_data, function(data){
            setPaginationData(data, table_config.table.id);
            // pagination[table_config.table.id] = data;
            loadingData(table_config.table.id, false);
        });
    }
}

function loadingData(table_id, check) {
    if(check == true){
        downloadingData = true;

        $('.'+table_id+'_loading_data').show();
    } else {
        downloadingData = false;
        $('.'+table_id+'_loading_data').hide();
    }
}
```

Shouldn't my searchTable function set the data in my object to the new value from the AJAX call?

Comment: Are you sure that the *table_id* you're using is the same?

Comment: To @MarioAlexandroSantini's point: The only way it could be different is if `populateTable` changes the `table_config` it receives. Does `populateTable` do that?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder No it does not.

Comment: I suggest creating a [mcve] in the question using Stack Snippets (the `<>` toolbar button) to make it runnable, and simulating the ajax with `setTimeout`. You're likely to find the problem, and if you don't, you have something that demonstrates it that we can help you with.

Comment: Side note: If you want to use that `debug == true ? doSomething() : false` style of debugging line (which I don't recommend; just put it in a function), you can make it shorter by doing `debug == true && doSomething();`

Comment: Could you provide the code of *loadingData*?

Comment: @MarioAlexandroSantini I edited the post to include it. Wasn't really relevant thou.

Comment: @DigitalFire I see now, was just to have a whole vision.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your function *getNextPage()* you make a post call to the server to retrieve the data.

You have already done in your function *searchTable()*, where you got the new pagination data.

So back in *getNextPage()* you pass the variable *page_data*, that is global and never change.

Maybe in this part you get back the original pagination object and you reset it.

Comment: Maybe your problem is the *page_data* as it didn't change?

Comment: well, page_data is set on initial page load and it is reset during the searchTable function. Also my headers during the AJAX call within the searchTable method is showing the right headers. The problem is that during searchTable method when I run "setPaginationData(data, table_config.table.id);" It doesn't actually set the global object.

Comment: Could you explain why? As you assign the value in the first line of the function. Anyway, if this is the answer I'll remove my answer.